# How can I have an array indexed by an array: Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I'm trying to create an array to collect students, and a grades array for each student. My int count will increment with a while loop or something. The problem is my Students array gets an error. Is there an alternative method?

```
static int count = 0;

static int[] Grades = new int[count];

static String[] Students =  new String[Grades[count];
```

Comment: Consider writing a `Student` class and then use a `Student[]` or a `List<Student>`.

Comment: Maybe consider a `Map<Student, Grade>`

Comment: With `count` set to 0, you'll always have a zero-length array, which you can never index into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

**To add:**

```
String student = "Bobby";
int mark = 85;
if (map.containsKey(student))
  map.get(student).add(mark);
else
{
  ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  arr.add(mark);
  map.put(student, arr);
}
```

**To display:**

```
System.out.println(map);
```

or:

```
for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry: map.entrySet())
  System.out.println("Marks of " + entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
```

**To extend functionality to allow students to have more properties:**

```
class Student
{
  ArrayList<Integer> marks;
  // ...
}
```

Declaration:

```
Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Student class which contains name, age...etc and an Array/List of grades :

```
class Student {
  String name;
  String age;
  //...
  List<Integer> grades;

  //Getters & Setters of course
}
```

You can add a method that grab a map of {name:grades}

Answer (score 1):

This design will create lot many problems for you in future. If you really want to stick with array., Do consider two dimensional arrays.

A better and clean design will be to use maps as follows.

```
map<Student, List<Grades>>  studentGrades= new Hashmap <Student, List<Grades>>() ;
```

Comment: If you can use 3rd party libraries then there is the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a two-dimentional array. something like an array of arrays, that each item holds an entire array:

```
int[][] students = new int[num_of_students][]
```

Then you can dinamically change the length of each array for each student:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_stuent; i++)
     students[i] = new int[i + 1]
```